# How to strip unused parameters from the url?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-routing

I'm using Zend Framework and the URL View Helper to create URLs

I have some lines like this in my navigation:

```
$this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'))
$this->url(array('controller' => 'who', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => $row->who_id));
$this->url(array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => $row->mai_id));
$this->url(array('controller' => 'content', 'action' => 'view', 'type' => 'theater', 'id' => $row->the_id));
$this->url(array('controller' => 'shows', 'action' => 'view'));
```

This way, at first, I have some URL like this

```
http://ccgss.local/information/location
http://ccgss.local/who/view/id/1
```

But when I access another link with more parameters like `http://ccgss.local/content/view/id/1/type/theater`
it messes up with the parameters that still were there: `http://ccgss.local/who/view/id/1/type/theater`

I mean, the parameters don't clean up when I access another page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reset parameters when calling `url` helper.

> $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'), null, true);

The second argument is the name of the route to use. Keep it `null` if you want to use the current route.
The third argument tells whether or not to reset parameters. It's `false` by default. 
So, just set it to `true` to get rid of existing parameters.